# How does {{}}s work in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a newbie and I wonder how does the {}s work in AngularJS like:

```
    <p>Hi, {{user}}</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate

Comment: What do you exactly want to know? Be a bit more specific. No one will answer a question like "how does angular work?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They compile your data.

Quick example:

In controller:

```
$scope.user = "Someone who don't read the basics in the manual";
```

In view:

```
<p>Hi, {{user}}</p>
<input ng-model="user" /> <!-- whenever this input field changes, the {{user}} above also changes -->
```

Comment: So is it just like a variable in javascript?

Comment: Could I do something like:
`open = document.body.split("{{");
close = open.split("}}");
open.replace("Username");
close.replace("");`

Sorry for asking you so much

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the Basics:

The `{{}}` are a declarative way of specifying data binding locations in the HTML. AngularJS will automatically update this text whenever the "user" property changes.